# How to pass the rows object to DataGrid in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-community-toolkit

I have a DataGrid in UWP and I want to bind the object for a row into a user control I've created.  I have the syntax to bind the properties of the object for that row, but I'd like to bind the entire object model.

In the below XAML I have bound to a list of a Direction Model (that implements INotifyPropertyChanged) and am able to pass in the properties.  I can't seem to get the syntax correct to pass the entire "Direction" object from that row.  I have tried various answers I've seen here without success yet.

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="DirectionDataGrid" ItemsSource="{x:Bind DirectionList, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Command" Width="*">
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Direction">
                    <controls1:DirectionEditorTextBox Text="{Binding Speedwalk, Mode=TwoWay}"></controls1:DirectionEditorTextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

I did get what's probably a hack to work.  I put a property on the "Direction" object that is a reference to itself (and that worked).

```
public Direction SelfReference
{
    get
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then the XAML:

```
<controls1:DirectionEditorTextBox Direction="{Binding SelfReference, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

This worked but I suspect there's a correct way to set it in the binding tag that I'm missing.

Comment: There is really no problem with what you have written. What is done in binding is to bind the properties in the Model to the control. It is feasible to pass Direction as an attribute “SelfReference” in the Model to DirectionEditorTextBox, this is a correct way.

Comment: That's good to know and I appreciate the advice, thank you Barry.